# How to replace \n into html <br> in a QWeb pdf report? Odoo 16

Tags: python, xml, pdf, odoo, report

I want to replace '\n' of python code by `<br/>` in qweb report.
In _get_report_values function , I have this result :

```
my_value :
 1 X product01
 2 X product02
```

In the report PDF , I have a table , and I want to display the content like this :

[image]

I tried with this code

```
  <td>
      <span t-esc="my_value.replace('\n', '&lt;br&gt;')"> </span>
   </td>
```

but I got :
[image]

Any help please ?

Thanks.